# How to initiate Java Aspose Barcode in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, aspose.barcode

**Jar placement** -
Aspose.BarCode.jar and servlet.jar files have been placed under the ColdFusion Instance as per [Aspose site for word](https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/coldfusion-and-aspose-words-for-java/)

> Jar path: ColdFusion2016\Instance-1\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib

**Code**
The code I am trying to run, all failed.

```
 try {
            somevar=5;
            pdflib1 = createObject("java","com.pdflib.pdflib");
            writedump("pdflib1 initiated");
    //below did not worked
            
            //asposeObj = CreateObject("java", "com.aspose.barcode.generation.BarCodeGenerator");
            asposeObj = CreateObject("java", "com.aspose.barcode.BarCodeGenerator");

//below code worked
            //asposeObj = CreateObject("java", "com.aspose.barcode.BarCodeException");
        }
        catch(any ex){  
            writedump(ex);
        }
```

Error it is giving class not found.

> ClassName Aspose.Barcode.BarCodeBuilder Detail    Class not found:
> Aspose.Barcode.BarCodeBuilder
> ErrorMessage  Aspose.Barcode.BarCodeBuilder Message   Object
> Instantiation Exception. RootCause     struct
> Message   Aspose.Barcode.BarCodeBuilder
> StackTrace    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> Aspose.Barcode.BarCodeBuilder at
> coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:303)
> at java.base/java.lan

Can someone please suggest how to initiate Java Aspose Barcode?

Comment: Did you install the jar file in an appropriate folder (one included in the classpath for ColdFusion)?  After doing that, did you restart the ColdFusion service to pick up the new file?

Comment: yes jar file was placed as 1st step. ColdFusion services were also restarted.

Comment: Hrm well the error suggests CF doesn't think the jar file is there. Where exactly did you put it (don't answer here, update the question as this is critical information to the question you are asking).

Comment: Thanks @AdamCameron , jar path has been updated in Question,

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue, adding answer here for other to refer.
The c is small in class name, BarcodeGenerator. My mistake was to use it as Bar**C**odeGenerator, however it should be Bar**c**odeGenerator
Working code

```
<cfscript>
writedump("aspose before test");

try {
    asposeObj = CreateObject("java", "com.aspose.barcode.generation.BarcodeGenerator");
    writedump("asposeObj initiated");
}
catch(any ex){  
    writedump(ex);
}
```